# Why full calendar doesn't appear in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

My problem when I use MySQL server, the calendar was appear but when I change the connection to SQL server the calendar doesn't appear. I have no idea how to solve this problem. Is that anything that I have to change the code to make the calendar appear?

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Confirm() {
        var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
        confirm_value.type = "hidden";
        confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
        if (confirm("Do you want to proceed ?")) {
            confirm_value.value = "Yes";
        } else {
            confirm_value.value = "No";
        }
        document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ConfirmEvent() {
        var confirm_value_event = document.createElement("INPUT");
        confirm_value_event.type = "hidden";
        confirm_value_event.name = "confirm_value_event";
        if (confirm("Do you want to proceed ?")) {
            confirm_value_event.value = "Yes";
        } else {
            confirm_value_event.value = "No";
        }
        document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value_event);
    }
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    .style1 {
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 120px;
    }
    .style2 {
        color: Blue;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: underline;
        height: 25px;
    }
    .style5 {
        color: Blue;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    .style6 {
        width: 96px;
    }
    .style7 {
        width: 150px;
    }
</style>

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

    <div id='calendar'>
    </div>
```

VB.NET:

```
     Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Public eventstring As String
"server=xxx.xxx.x.x\SQLEXPRESS;database=attendance;uid=ab;pwd=abcde;"
    Dim Conn As SqlConnection
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim rdmysql As SqlDataReader
    Dim strsql As String
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim lbl As Label = Master.FindControl("lblHeader")
    lbl.Text = "IT Attendance"


    Dim startdate As String = Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd")
    If txtStartDate.Value = "" Then txtStartDate.Value = startdate
    If txtEndDate.Value = "" Then txtEndDate.Value = startdate
    If txtStartEvent.Value = "" Then txtStartEvent.Value = startdate
    If txtEndEvent.Value = "" Then txtEndEvent.Value = startdate

    Conn = New SqlConnection
    Conn.ConnectionString = ConnStr
    Conn.Open()

    eventstring = ""

    strsql = "SELECT * FROM record;"
    cmd = New SqlCommand
    cmd.Connection = Conn
    cmd.CommandText = strsql
    rdmysql = cmd.ExecuteReader
    Do While rdmysql.Read = True
        eventstring = eventstring & "{title: '" & rdmysql.GetString(1) & " - " & rdmysql.GetString(3) & "', start: '" & rdmysql.GetString(2) & "',  color: 'yellow', borderColor: 'black', textColor: 'black'},"

    Loop
    cmd.Dispose()
    rdmysql.Close()

    strsql = "SELECT * FROM event;"
    cmd = New SqlCommand
    cmd.Connection = Conn
    cmd.CommandText = strsql
    rdmysql = cmd.ExecuteReader
    Do While rdmysql.Read = True
        eventstring = eventstring & "{title: '" & rdmysql.GetString(1) & "', start: '" & rdmysql.GetString(2) & "', color: 'skyblue', textColor: 'black', borderColor: 'black'},"

    Loop
    cmd.Dispose()
    rdmysql.Close()
    eventstring = Mid(eventstring, 1, Len(eventstring) - 1)
```

Anyone can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry, I don't see anything relate SQL or MySQL.

Comment: none of the code you've shown has anything to do with SQL. None of it relates to fullCalendar either, come to that. If you've changed some code relating to SQL, it would make sense to show that. Also have you checked your server code for exceptions? And checked your client-side code for console and/or ajax errors? You haven't said what debugging you've done. If you're not getting any events, or the calendar is not showing, there's likely an error somewhere you can look for. But without any of the relevant code, or any error reports, there's really no way we can help you further.

Comment: @ADyson I already update my source code

Comment: thanks, but you still haven't answered any of my other questions: Have you checked your server code for exceptions? And checked your client-side code for console and/or ajax errors? What debugging have you done, to find the place where the problem occurs? You need to _describe your problem in detail_, not just dump the code. "Not working" is not a sufficient description to help you. If you've changed the DB code, start debugging from there. Step through the code until it breaks, and note the error. Also, why is this tagged with Web API? There's no Web API code here, just some ASP.NET Forms.

Comment: Also, there's still nothing to describe how you populate the fullCalendar from the database. Please show your calendar config. and also show how you return the `eventstring` to the client - at the moment your code ends with you creating a string, and then doing nothing with it. You've missed out a lot of relevant information. We need to see the whole chain from start to finish..._unless_ you can tell us the exact error and where it occurs, and then maybe we only need to see that bit of code.